# assigning urdu text to variable in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to work with urdu text in sql ?

i have urdu text:

ے ایڈیٹر یا پھر کیبورڈ کو استعمال کریں۔ایڈیٹر سے تمام لکھائی کاپی کری

now how to assign it to variable ?

e.g.

```
 Declare @msg nvarchar(1600)
    Set @msg= '
اپکی سثیکایت درج کردی گیؑ ھے۔ سثیکایت کوڈ یہ ہے ۔ معلومات حاصل کرنے کے لئے اسی کوڈ کو بھیجیں -شکریہ'
    Select @msg
```

it returns `??????????????????????????????????????`

and would c# help also needed, would it work there after selecting from sql ?

Update:

I am assigning Urdu text to a variable in c# but it doesn't work like when paste it, it's in reverse order and throws many errors. Why ?

I copied this text

```
اپکی سثیکایت درج کردی گیؑ ھے۔ سثیکایت کوڈ یہ ہے ۔ معلومات حاصل کرنے کے لئے اسی کوڈ کو بھیجیں -شکریہ
```

it's in proper format, no problem but when i assign same string to c# variable then it becomes reverse and multiple errors

```
String Urdu_Msg = "
اپکی سثیکایت درج کردی گیؑ ھے۔ سثیکایت کوڈ یہ ہے ۔ معلومات حاصل کرنے کے لئے اسی کوڈ کو بھیجیں -شکریہ";
```

it still works in stack overflow, the text assigned to variable in proper format but in visual studio .cs file it's in reverse plus errors

```
Unexpected character 'ؑ'    
Unexpected character '۔'
```

why ? help ?
I am using asp.net C#.net 4.0

Comment: You have a line break in your string literal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though you declare an nvarchar variable, sql server does not understand that the literal is supposed to use unicode encoding and tries to interpret the string using non-unicode encoding. Use an nvarchar literal by prefixing your string with `N`

**i.e.** `N'ے ایڈیٹر یا پھر کیبورڈ کو استعمال کریں۔ایڈیٹر سے تمام لکھائی کاپی کری'`

C# uses unicode, so shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: N ? what is is used for ?

Comment: Sir well done but one problem in c#, i am updating my code, please check

Answer (score 2):

You have a second issue.  It appears editing Urdu text strings in the Visual Studio editor is problematic.  Putting a right-to-left text string within a left-to-right programming language is supposed to work, but sometimes the editor confuses things.

It may be easier to put these strings in resources, or at least edit them in a Unicode-aware text editor, and paste them back into Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

first convert your text to base code on net2ftp editor, put your code in editor and submit, editor change text in to base code automatically
like...

`&#1575;&#1662;&#1705;&#1740; &#1587;&#1579;&#1740;&#1705;&#1575;&#1740;&#1578; &#1583;&#1585;&#1580; &#1705;&#1585;&#1583;&#1740; &#1711;&#1740;&#1553; &#1726;&#1746;&#1748; &#1587;&#1579;&#1740;&#1705;&#1575;&#1740;&#1578; &#1705;&#1608;&#1672; &#1740;&#1729; &#1729;&#1746; &#1748; &#1605;&#1593;&#1604;&#1608;&#1605;&#1575;&#1578; &#1581;&#1575;&#1589;&#1604; &#1705;&#1585;&#1606;&#1746; &#1705;&#1746; &#1604;&#1574;&#1746; &#1575;&#1587;&#1740; &#1705;&#1608;&#1672; &#1705;&#1608; &#1576;&#1726;&#1740;&#1580;&#1740;&#1722; -&#1588;&#1705;&#1585;&#1740;&#1729;`

result:
اپکی سثیکایت درج کردی گیؑ ھے۔ سثیکایت کوڈ یہ ہے ۔ معلومات حاصل کرنے کے لئے اسی کوڈ کو بھیجیں -شکریہ

[basecode](/questions/tagged/basecode)[net2ftp](/questions/tagged/net2ftp)[unicode](/questions/tagged/unicode)[urdu](/questions/tagged/urdu)[sql](/questions/tagged/sql)